$\begin{pmatrix}u(x)&v(x)\\ -g(x)&f(x)\end{pmatrix}$ to be the identity matrix $I_2$

Let polynomials satisfy $u(x)f(x)+v(x)g(x)=1$. How can we use elemenary row/column transform $\begin{pmatrix}u(x)&v(x)\\ -g(x)&f(x)\end{pmatrix}$ to be the identity matrix $I_2$?

$\begin{pmatrix}u(x)&v(x)-u(x)f(x)\\ -g(x)&f(x)+f(x)g(x)\end{pmatrix}$?
Or $u(x)=1+u(x)-u(x)f(x)-v(x)g(x)$. It seems to hard to transform one entry to be exactly $1$.

I answered this same question, posted an hour before. Without an accepted or upvoted answer, I can't seem to nominate this as a duplicate, so a link will have to do.

Case 1. First consider those $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for which $v(x)f(x) \neq 0$. Then,
$$\begin{bmatrix}u&v\\-g&f\end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{fR_1} \begin{bmatrix}uf&vf\\-g&f\end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{-vR_2}\begin{bmatrix}uf&vf\\vg&-vf\end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{R_2+R_1}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\vg&-vf\end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{-vgR_1+R_2} \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-vf\end{bmatrix}.$$
By our assumption $v(x)f(x) \neq 0$, so
$$ \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-vf\end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{\frac{-1}{vf}R_2} \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$
Case 2: Suppose $v(x_0)f(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0$. Note that we cannot have BOTH $v(x_0)=0$ and $f(x_0)=0$, otherwise $uf+vg=1$ will not hold. So, say $f(x_0)=0$, then we have $v(x_0)g(x_0)=1$. Then,
$$\begin{bmatrix}u(x_0)&v(x_0)\\-1/v(x_0)&0\end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{R_1 \circlearrowleft R_2}\begin{bmatrix}-1/v(x_0)&0\\u(x_0)&v(x_0)\end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{-v(x_0)R_1}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\u(x_0)&v(x_0)\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{-u(x_0)R_1+R_2}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&v(x_0)\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{\frac{1}{v(x_0)}R_2}I_2.$$
Note: In the last step we are using the fact that $v(x_0) \neq 0$.
